# JSF Request Scoped Bean not displaying data in page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm experimenting with JSF scopes, and have some issues when using a session scoped bean within a request scoped bean.

The basic workflow is that the user would click a View button on an item from the home page, which then calls my code to load & display that item's information.

Here's my **UPDATED** code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="itemViewBean")
@RequestScoped
class ItemViewBean {
    @ManagedProperty("#{itemBean}")
    private ItemBean itemBean;

    private ItemViewObject itemViewObject;
    private int itemId;

    public void init() {
         itemViewObject = itemBean.readItem(itemId);
    }

    public String readItem(int itemId) {
     //     itemViewObject = itemBean.readItem(itemId);  // moved to init();
          return "/pages/viewItem.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public ItemViewObject getItemViewObject() {
          return itemViewObject;
    }

    // getters & setters as needed

}

@ManagedBean(name="itemBean")
@SessionScoped
class ItemBean {
    public ItemViewObject readItem(int itemId) {
        // hardcoded creating a ItemViewObject for now.
        // eventually would be loaded from the database.
        ....
    }
}
```

My **UPDATED** view page then has things like:

```
<!-- added the metadata -->
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{itemViewBean.itemId}" />
    <f:event listener="#{itemViewBean.init}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>

<!-- same as before -->
<h:outputText value="#{itemViewBean.itemViewObject.description}" />
```

If my viewBean is request scoped (or view scoped), I get empty data on the view page.  If the viewBean is session scoped, things work.  And I'm not understanding why?

From what I see in my debugger, readItem(itemId) is called (from the home page when clicking a view button), but when the view page itself calls the getItemViewObject(), the itemViewObject is null.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention earlier how my home page was calling readItem method, and that was through a command button:

```
<h:commandButton class="btn btn-mini firefoxBtnMiniCorrection"
    value="View"
    action="#{itemViewBean.readItem(b.itemId)}"/>
```

Each item listed in the home page has its own View button.

Also forgot to mention that both the home page and my view page are using JSF Templates.  I don't know if that matters.

From the comments below which people have made, I came up with the code changes above.  And things work now.  Using either request scope or view scope with ItemViewBean works now.

And I am surprised this worked!  I'm not quite certain I fully understand why it works.

Are my changes the correct way to do things?  Or is there a better way?

Also, I'm using JSF 2.1.

**Update 2**
It doesn't work.  The scoping works, but I discovered that the itemId in the viewParam is always null. Why?

Comment: I personally don't like this kind of flow. Why do you really need to have this kind of data in session? If you're going to display it for a specific view, just load it in the `@ViewScoped` bean. The method which loads the initial data for the view should be called [through a `f:viewAction` binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377957/1199132), this ensures it is called only once, thus not making unecessary calls to the DB.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks.  Based on the post you sited, plus looking at an article from BalusC, I updated the code above.  And things work.  Is there any other way, or better way, to do this?  Thanks again!

Comment: this was the [article](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)  from @BalusC I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

`itemViewObject` is private in a `RequestScoped` bean. After `readItem()` got a value for itemViewObject, this value will be forgotten after this request and will be null at the next request (`@RequestScoped').